SQL Reporting Service installation
I'm trying to install SSRS 2019 Dev on clean VM (Windows Server 2019 Std, SQL Server 2019 Dev) and encounter next error:
    [18E8:06DC][2024-04-03T12:26:11]e000: UnexpectedError: Burn engine encountered error. PackageId: SSReportingServicesSetup, ErrorType: WindowsInstaller, ErrorCode: -2147483648, Data: , ErrorMessage: Something went wrong, please find details in setup logs.CallStack:
ЌҐ®Ўа Ў®в ­­®Ґ ЁбЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: System.Exception: ManagementException -    ў System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   ў System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)
   ў System.Management.ManagementObject.get_ClassPath()
   ў System.Management.ManagementObject.GetMethodParameters(String methodName, ManagementBaseObject& inParameters, IWbemClassObjectFreeThreaded& inParametersClass, IWbemClassObjectFreeThreaded& outParametersClass)
   ў System.Management.ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(String methodName, Object args)
   ў Microsoft.BIServer.Configuration.RsService.SetServiceAccountPassword(AccountCredentials accountCredentials)
   ў Microsoft.BIServer.Setup.RsServiceInstaller.Create()
   ў SetupEngine.Install()
   ў SetupEngine.Execute()
   ў Microsoft.BIServer.Setup.Setup.Main(String cmdLine)
   ў Microsoft.BIServer.Setup.Setup.Main(String cmdLine)
, UIHint: 0
[18E8:06DC][2024-04-03T12:26:11]i000: User: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services: Something went wrong, please find details in setup logs.
[18E8:06DC][2024-04-03T12:26:11]e000: UnexpectedError: setup failed for packageId: SSReportingServicesSetup, package: Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services, errorCode: -2147483648, errorMessage: Something went wrong, please find details in setup logs.
[18E8:06DC][2024-04-03T12:26:11]i000: Setup: Install Completed for package Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services

I tried to install/unistall multiple times and spend several hours with different combinations on Google, but all in vain.
Any help will be appreciated.
